# What exactly are the restrictions on the System.Diagnostics.Process.Start method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

MSDN states:

> ASP.NET Web page and server control code executes in the context of
>   the ASP.NET worker process on the Web server. If you use the Start
>   method in an ASP.NET Web page or server control, the new process
>   executes on the Web server with restricted permissions. The process
>   does not start in the same context as the client browser, and does not
>   have access to the user desktop.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb(v=vs.110).aspx

Other than not having access to the desktop, are there any other restrictions?

MSDN states that "the process does not start in the same context as the client browser . . . ." So what? ASP.NET does not run as the client browser any ways.

So, what security context does it run as? If it runs as the same security context as the ASP.NET worker process (which I guess refers to the w3wp) then that's not really more restrictive.

If the newly started process has more restrictions that the worker process, then what exactly are those extra restrictions?

Here it claims that the newly spawned process inherits the security context from the parent ASP.NET worker process:

> The Process class in System.Diagnostics can start a new process, but
>   the process always inherits the security context of the parent
>   process. Even if the ASP.NET thread invoking the Start method is
>   impersonating a client, the Process still starts with the ASP.NET
>   worker process credentials.
>   http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2004/10/28/createprocessasuser.aspx

Does the new process inherit all of the parent ASP.NET worker process permissions? If so, then how is it more restricted?

So, what exactly are the restricted permissions?

Comment: The `the process does not start in the same context as the client browser...` text is there because you'd be surprised how many new web developers seem to think that `Process.Start` is capable of launching programs on the client machine.

Comment: Those processes will also run under the account that the AppPool is running as.  Since that account doesn't (usually) have a profile attached to it, the applications may hit errors or not behave properly if they try to do something that requires access to a profile.

Comment: "...a profile attached ...." I guess that's the "Load User Profile" Boolean variable in an application pool's advanced settings ?